# Do Multiple Hypothesis Tests Offer more Information that Testing each Hypothesis Individually?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

I have the following question: **Do Multiple Hypothesis Tests Offer more Information that Testing each Hypothesis Individually?**

To illustrate my example, suppose you have samples of the salaries earned by randomly selected individuals in 3 different towns (I have included R code to create this hypothetical data):

```
#first sample
a = rnorm(100,20000,1000)

a2 = rnorm(100,40000,10000)

a1 = rnorm(100,100000,10000)

salary = c(a,a1, a2)
id = 1:length(salary)

town1_sample = data.frame(id, salary)

#second sample
salary = rnorm(400, 50000, 10000)
id = 1:length(salary)
town2_sample = data.frame(id, salary)


#third sample
a = rnorm(100,20000,1000)
a2 = rnorm(100,40000,10000)
salary = c(a, a2)
id = 1:length(salary)

town3_sample = data.frame(id, salary)
```

The histograms of the samples from these 3 towns look as follow:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

 hist(town1_sample$salary,  50, ylab = "Number of People" , xlab = " Salary ",   main="Sample From 1st Town" )

 hist(town2_sample$salary,  50, ylab = "Number of People" , xlab = " Salary ",   main="Sample From 2nd Town" )

hist(town3_sample$salary,  50, ylab = "Number of People" , xlab = " Salary ",   main="Sample From 3rd Town" )
```

[image]

**My Question** : Suppose for each of these 3 towns, I want to test the hypothesis that 50% of people earn more than $50,000. I can set up 3 separate hypothesis tests:

[image]

**HYPOTHESIS TEST FOR SAMPLE 1**

**Actual Proportion of People in Town 1 who Earn More than $50, 000:**

```
sum(ifelse(town1_sample$salary > 50000,1,0)) / nrow(town1_sample)
[1] 0.3866667
```

- **Null Hypothesis:** Ho = proportion of people earning more than $50, 000 = 0.5
- **Alternate Hypothesis:** Ho = proportion of people earning more than $50, 000 <> 0.5
- **Test Statistics** : `Z = (0.5 - 0.386) / sqrt(0.386*(1 - 0.386) / nrow(town1_sample)) = 4.055904`

**HYPOTHESIS TEST FOR SAMPLE 2**

**Actual Proportion of People in Town 2 who Earn More than $50, 000:**

```
 `sum(ifelse(town2_sample$salary > 50000,1,0)) / nrow(town2_sample)
[1] 0.52 `
```

- **Null Hypothesis:** Ho = proportion of people earning more than $50, 000 = 0.5
- **Alternate Hypothesis:** Ho = proportion of people earning more than $50, 000 <> 0.5
- **Test Statistics** :

  `Z = abs((0.5 - 0.52)) / sqrt(0.52*(1 - 0.52) / nrow(town2_sample)) = 0.80`

**HYPOTHESIS TEST FOR SAMPLE 3**

**Actual Proportion of People in Town 3 who Earn More than $50, 000:**

```
 `sum(ifelse(town3_sample$salary > 50000,1,0)) / nrow(town3_sample)
[1] 0.05 `
```

- **Null Hypothesis:** Ho = proportion of people earning more than $50, 000 = 0.5
- **Alternate Hypothesis:** Ho = proportion of people earning more than $50, 000 <> 0.5
- **Test Statistics** :

  `Z = abs((0.5 - 0.05)) / sqrt(0.05*(1 - 0.05) / nrow(town3_sample)) = 29.19`

**My Question:** In the above example, I have tested each hypothesis individually. Would there have been any statistical benefits in jointly testing all the hypotheses? Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: when you say “jointly testing”, do you mean testing “proportion of people earning more than $50,000” in the 3 cities all together? (independently of the city)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I meant: the probability that all null hypothese are "true" together. Or is it the same as each being true individually and just multiplied together?

Comment: Oh.. I just realized that you mentioned "Multiple hypothesis testing" in the title. I managed to miss it! So, I think this is what you meant when you said "jointly". My understanding is that multiple comparisons are actually multiple statistical tests performed on the same data set, while in your example, you have 3 samples and 3 independent tests... Probably you could clarify this part?

Comment: thank you for your reply! yes, there are 3 independent samples - do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: Sorry, but I must be missing something since I am not sure to understand your ultimate goal. Probably it resides in your previous comment "the probability that all null hypothese are true". If this is the case, the p-value of each individual test will not tell you that. The p-value give you the probability of obtaining test results at least as extreme as the observed result (from your sample). So, combining the 3 will be challenging to interpret.